# save and query data from firestore with timeStamp or firebase server time in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Please I have a history page on my flutter app that I want to work on and I have been thinking of a way to store the data correctly in my firestore so that I can achieve the desired result as seen in the picture below

[image: here is the picture]

I would love to have data of thesame day stored in thesame container as seen in the picture above. My challenge is, I do not know how to structure my data to get the desired result.

here is what I have tried;

my Count class file is below although I am not sure if that's what I will really do.

```
class Count {
 String id;
 final int count;
 final createdOn;

 Count({this.id = '', required this.count, required this.createdOn});

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
     {'id': id, "count": count, "createdOn": createdOn};

 Count.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
     : id = snapshot.id,
       count = snapshot.data()!["count"],
       createdOn = snapshot.data()!["createdOn"];
}
```

and this is where I send data to firestore using onpressed in button

```
 onPressed: () async {
                               exerciseCounter.increment();
                               final counter = exerciseCounter.count;

                               final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

                               final User? user = await auth.currentUser;

                               final uid = user?.uid;

                               final percents = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                   .collection('exercise-percentage')
                                   .doc(uid)
                                   .collection("daily-percentage");

                               final percent = Count(
                                   count: counter,
                                   createdOn: FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                               final json = percent.toJson();

                               await percents.add(json);
                             },
```

now I am not sure of the correct way to use streambuilder to get the data from firestore and join the data of thesame day in thesame container. I understand that I will need to use query method to query my data with the firestore serverTimeStamp  but I don't know how to use it to fetch data of thesame day and display it as shown in the picture above.

I will appreciate it if someone can really help me out. It can just be with a simple example I can follow or by correcting and adding to my code. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> I would love to have data of the same day stored in the same container
> as seen in the picture above.

You could have an extra field beside the `createdOn` one which holds the date in the following format YYYYMMDD.

This way, you can easily:

- Query the Firestore document for a specific day
- Use a set of [count aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) to calculate the KPIs/Counters for a specific day